# I cannot pull with source tree in github

Tags: gitlab, atlassian-sourcetree, git-pull

I am trying to pull in gitlab with source tree but unable to do so.

> git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false fetch origin
>   remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied fatal: Authentication failed for
>   'http://davy_yg@git.amanahcorp.com/daffi_gusti/soulfy_repo3.git/'
>   remote: Forbidden fatal: unable to access
>   'http://davy_yg@git.amanahcorp.com/daffi_gusti/soulfy_repo3.git/': The
>   requested URL returned error: 403 Completed with errors, see above.

How to fix the error so that I can pull and push?

Answer (score 0):

See [issue 6576](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/6576) as a way to troubleshoot this issue.

For instance, you can:

- try and see if cloning through ssh work
- look for the `production.log` for a more precise error
- check the project visibility to compare [against the user permissions](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/permissions.html#project) (a public project for instance should require no authentication)